# How to cancel iron python scripts without aborting thread

Tags: ironpython

Is there a way to cancel iron python code execution without aborting the executing thread?

Comment: How are you running the script?

Comment: @D.Alveno I'm running it in a hosted environment , using Task.Run()

Comment: @Chris what about passing a `CancelationToken`?

Comment: @BendEg to pass it where?